# MySQL slow query skyrocket irregularly

Tags: mysql, performance

I am running mobile service with MySQL.

Normally there is a few slow log. (less than 0.5/sec)
But sometimes it goes so high in short duration. (more then 6/sec)

[image]

I checked slow query log, they were not specific queries, but all of my queries. So I guess it might be locking issue, but in slow query logs there are only "query_time", "lock_time" is always 0.

And I checked server status but nothing special.

Now I don't even have a clue. What should I look first?

Comment: DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question rather than developers. However, you should do some more research because all anybody can do atm is to give you a list of things that can slow queries down.

Comment: I understood, doing research to find out. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the query in question, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Also, look around in the Slowlog for other slow queries "at the same time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a reason.

Somebody in company(who is not programmer so I didn't recognize him) occasionally executed queries for statistics.

Those queries don't care about time, and no effect on live users. So he sometimes did that with no consideration.

After it stopped, slow query ratio is just fine.

I am sorry to submit bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the query marked as slow. create index in all table related in the query using column in joins, where and group statements.

Example

```
Select 
  a.name, 
  count(*) as trans_count, 
  sum(b.trans_value) as trans_tot_value
From 
   tbl_customer a inner join 
   tbl_orders b 
      on a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
 Where 
     a.city ='jakarta' 
     and b.date = today()
  Group by a.name
```

Then you should create indexes

1. Idx_customer_id on tbl_customer consists of customer_id column.
2. Idx_customer_id on tbl_orders consists of customer_id column.
3. Idx_city on tbl_customer consists of city column.
4. Idx_trans_date on tbl_orders consists of date column.
5. Idx_customer_name on tbl_customer consists of customer name column.

Analyzing the query and index used on table can help improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks, but can it explain the situation? I mean, if index is the problem, maybe it will be slow all times, not specific moment.

Comment: It depends on the amount of data request and resources utilization. If you have a detail log, you could try to cross check between Apache log, mysql slow query log, memory utilization and cpu utilization. Without using index, joins, group by , order by and where operation will use table scan to compare values in each row. It consume much higher cpu cycles and disk io than using index.  If the connection request to the server  is high enough when the query execute. There will process queuing. The higher web and sql requests , the longer the queue , thus longer execution time

Comment: There are many technics to optimize your service as a whole, not just the MySQL. For instance, you could implement data caching in the web service. But that in application side.  You could also analize your query using mysql explain syntax.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to get more detail

there might be more reason

Slow queries
Too many connections
Too many queries per second
Resource Utilization
and much more

you can go for more detail

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60138/how-to-determine-why-a-mysql-server-has-become-slow-and-requests-sometimes-time

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-query-profiling

Comment: Okay, I will check it.